# How can I configure hadoop rpc's timeout?

Tags: hadoop, rpc

My application program uses hadoop's rpc to remotely send/receive the requests in distributed environment.

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC;
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.Server;

....

this.server = RPC.getServer(this, this.peerAddr.getHostName(), this.peerAddr.getPort(), this.conf);
this.server.start();
```

As the tasks get heavier, I observe frequent task failures due to IO Exception (that is possibly caused by thread interrupts).

I suspect the exception is being caused by a sort of RPC timeout.

How can I adjust the timeout for RPC in hadoop?
For example, what I am expecting is something like ...

```
<property>
<name>hadoop.rpc.timeout</name>
<value>3000</value>
<description>The timeout for RPC call in ms</description>
</property>
```

Comment: hadoop version ??

Comment: @mrsrinivas Hadoop version is 0.20 which is quite old. (The framework uses this version, which I don't know why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hadoop 0.20 doesn't support this, please read this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6889

Comment: I can see 'RpcTimeout' variable in hadoop ipc client code. (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/ipc/Client.java)